# Laravel 8: Target class does not exist ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8

I have two `ArticleController`, one of them is placed at `Admin` directory inside Controllers:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController as ArticleADMController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController;

Route::get('/articles/{articleSlug}' , [ArticleController::class, 'single']);
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('articles' , ArticleADMController::class)->except(['show']);
});
```

And now whenever I want to go to `/admin/articles` I get this message:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> **[Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController] does not exist.**

However, it does exist there as you can see in this pic:

[image: capture]

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

If you know, please help me out with this, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController notice Admin at the beginning, no idea why it was added though.

Comment: perhaps it's to do with ->namespace('Admin'), try to remove it.

Comment: You can't have same class in laravel project. I THINK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the namespace('Admin') from your route. You are adding prefix for the Admin/ArticleController. Since you have already used the namespace path you need not add any namespace separately in route group.

If it still not resolve the issue, please share the namespace declaration in your Admin\ArticleController.

Answer (score 0):

For Admin route: You are already specifying that the controller comes from the admin path, try this.

For Articles route: Removed "use" and included the full path directly in the path for "articles" route .

```
Route::get('/articles/{articleSlug}' , [App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::class, 'single']);
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('articles' , ArticleController::class)->except(['show']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 9, In a situation like this, this was my solution when I faced a similar problem

I found that my problem was being caused by this line `Route::resource('/blog', 'BlogController', ['except' => ['show']]);` in my web.php file

Initially my resource had been registered as `Route::resource('/blog', 'BlogController', ['except' => ['show']]);`

I went ahead and refactored it to `Route::resource('/blog', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController', ['except' => ['show']]);`

Then did `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan optimize` then `php artisan route:list`

That should solve the problem IF you are using `resources` and also see that you already have the namespace of the Controller at the top of the web.php file but are still facing the issue